# how to increase float without strange number

Tags: android

so i tried to increase number with float, but sometime it comes strange number but i just want a number like `0.1, 0.2, until 5.0` but it sometime comes with strange number like `0.9000001`

this is my code to increase the float

```
addRattingBtn.onClick {
        quantity += 0.1f
        if (quantity >= 5.0f) {
            toast("maximum")
            return@onClick
        }
        totalRatting(quantity.toBigDecimal())
    }
```

i already convert it to BigDecimal but it still not work.
why this is happen? and how to make it right. please help

Answer (score 2):

This is because the finite nonzero values of any floating-point value set can all be expressed in the form s · m · 2(e - N + 1), where s is +1 or -1, m is a positive integer less than 2N, and e is an integer between Emin = -(2K-1-2) and Emax = 2K-1-1, inclusive, and where N and K are parameters that depend on the value set. Hence, float values cannot accurately represent base 10 real numbers and as you go on adding them they loose the precision sometime and shows such results, you should be using big decimal for the precision.

For example:

```
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal(0.1);
BigDecimal add = number.add(new BigDecimal(0.1));
```

Comment: i already convert it to big decimal but it still don't want to work

Comment: Don't convert it, initialize and increment in big decimal only.

Comment: but how to initialize BigDecimal and increase them?

Comment: i mead add the value

Comment: I have modified my answer please have a look.